# How to disable the "Application permissions" dialog that pop up during each new app install?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, permissions, samsung-touchwiz, samsung-galaxy-a5

I have a Samsung Galaxy A5[18] running Android 4.4.4. Every time I install a new app this dialog comes up:

[image]

Is there any way to disable this feature?

I'm doing app development so I have to install my development app hundreds of times a day, making this dialog extremely annoying.

Comment: If you've got to install your test-app hundreds of times a day, I wonder you are not using `adb install` for that. No popups at all, just "silently" installs the app and gives feedback on the commandline ("success" or "fail").

Comment: I am using `adb install`. This dialog pops up regardless of how the app is installed.

Comment: Uh? Never heard such. And I use `adb install` a lot, on multiple devices. Maybe you can find out what app that is, and simply disable it when not wanted? After all, built-in permission management like that didn't come with Kitkat, which makes me assume a "3rd party" or vendor-specific app here (as the text reads a little strange: is "Hello scaloid! for sbt" the name of the app you install?).

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing either until I got this phone. Is this some crapware that all Samsung phones come with? I can't even find the name of this app. All I know is that it's shipped with the phone and can't be removed. Yes, "Hello scaloid! for sbt" is my test app.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it "crapware" – many users wish for this feature. To find the app, you could use an enhanced [Auto-Start Manager](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_autostart#group_847) and watch out for apps listening to the `PACKAGE_INSTALLED` broadcast. When found, disable that receiver. Requires root.

Comment: When that window pops-up again do `adb shell dumpsys activity | grep "Recent #0:"`  or `adb shell dumpsys activity | grep "mFocusedActivity"`. You would see the package name of the application launching that window. It seems to be Android Lollipop as per screenshot, so you can simply go to Settings -> Apps and look for that app corresponding to the package name.